# two functions are uniformly continuous on some interval I and each is bounded on I then their product is also uniformly continuous on I .

Tags: uniform-continuity

prove that if two real valued  functions are uniformly continuous on some interval $I$  and each is bounded on $I$ then their product $f\cdot g=f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is also uniformly continuous on $I$ . Is boundedness of each function  on $I$ is  necessary for the product

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let $x_0\in I$, using the definition of uniform continuity and the  boundedness of each function we prove that $fg$ is uniformly continuous at $x_0$ (and then on $I$) by the inequality

$$|f(x)g(x)-f(x_0)g(x_0)|=|f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x_0)+f(x)g(x_0)-f(x_0)g(x_0)|\\
\leq|f(x)||g(x)-g(x_0)|+|g(x_0)||f(x)-f(x_0)|\\\leq M|g(x)-g(x_0)|+M'|f(x)-f(x_0)|$$

Comment: How did you put those two bounds instead of $f(x)$ and $g(x_0)$ ?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are bounded on $I$ means that there's $M,M'\ge0$ such that $$|f(x)|\le M\quad;\quad |g(x)|\le M'\;\forall x\in I$$

Comment: OK, why did you replace those two terms and what does it mean ?

Comment: Do you know the definition that $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous?

Comment: The epsilon delta defintion ? yeah.

Comment: Yes apply this definition to the function $fg$ knowing that $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous.

Comment: You mean to apply it to this: $M|g(x)-g(x_0)|+M'|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ ? So $M|g(x)-g(x_0)|+M'|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ ? Still, I don't understand what does two bounds (M,M') mean here...

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$ since $f$ is uniformly continuous then there's $\eta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{M}$ whatever $|x-x_0|<\eta$. Do the same thing for $g$ and we find $|g(x)-g(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{M'}$ if $|x-x_0|<\eta'$. Now let $\delta=\min(\eta,\eta')$ and use the inequality of my answer to prove that $$|f(x)g(x)-f(x_0)g(x_0)|<\epsilon$$ if $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Comment: Why $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$ ? shouldn't it be for all epsilon ? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: @GinKin Surely $\epsilon$ is arbitrary but I divide by $M$ to find the final result $<\epsilon$. Cauchy has a famous saying: "Just cut $\epsilon$ out of 2";-)

Comment: Hehe I see, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example. $f(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, but not bounded. $f^{2}(x)=x^{2}$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: This answer the second part of the question.

Comment: i think you understand something wrong i want to ask if product is uniformly continuous then then it is not necessary that each function is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be uniformly continuous on a real interval $I$ with endpoints $0$ and $1$.

For any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in I$, $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

In particular, by the Archimedean property, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z_+$ such that for all $x,y\in I$, $|x-y|<\frac2n\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<1$. Then for any $x\in I$, $|f(x)-f(0)|<n$. Or something like that.