# Uniform continuity - Please check my work

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Iv'e got some questions involving uniform continuity of functions and its properties.
I would like that someone will check my work and maybe help with correcting flaws.

Let $A \subset R$ and let $f,g: \ A \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be uniformly continuous in A.

Prove or disprove:

- **f+g is uniformly continuous in A**:

  By definitions:

  - $\forall \epsilon'>0 \ \exists \delta_1>0: \ |x-y|<\delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon'$
  - $\forall \epsilon'>0 \ \exists \delta_2>0: \ |x-y|<\delta_2 \Rightarrow |g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon'$

Now, let $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $\delta=min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

By the triangle inequality we may write the following:
$|[f(x)-f(y)]+[g(x)-g(y)]| \leq |f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon'+\epsilon'=2\epsilon'$.

Let $\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ we get eventually:
$\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta>0: \ |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |h(x)-h(y)|<2\epsilon'=\epsilon$.

- **$f\cdot{g}$ is uniformly continuous in A** - This is false as we may take $f(x)=x, \ g(x)=x$.
- **f,g are bounded. $f\cdot{g}$ is uniformly continuous in A** - I have seen proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470813/two-functions-are-uniformly-continuous-on-some-interval-i-and-each-is-bounded-on) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345480/product-of-two-uniformly-continuous-functions-is-uniformly-continuous).
- **Given $A=\mathbb{R}$. $f \circ g$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$** - I have no clue - no matter what I tried to do, I get to dead end.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Note that $\delta={\epsilon}$.

Comment: How does it matter? where should I include it in my solution? Have I written the solution in a correct proper way?

Comment: Your Proof is ok. Just I wanted to point out the relation between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. See for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Comment: For the composition: Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta_1>0$ so that $|f(y)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|y-z|<\delta_1$. Now choose $\delta_2>0$ so that $|g(y)-g(z)|<\delta_1$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta_2$.

Comment: Mhenni, thanks, now it is understood. David, I'm familiar with the definitions and tried to start from definitions and elaborate, but no success. May you continue?

Comment: So, continuing with what I wrote, if $|x-y|<\delta_2$, it follows that $|f(g(x))-f(g(y))|<\epsilon$. As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f\circ g$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Seems fine, just another one question - in the second part you meant $|g(x)-g(y)|$, not $|g(y)-g(z)|$, true?

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry about the "typo".

Comment: @Galc127: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fine to me.

For your last question about the composition of $f$ and $g$. It might be wise to make a small sketch. $$x \overset{\delta_g}{\longrightarrow}g(x) \overset{\epsilon_g=\delta_f}{\longrightarrow}f(g(x))$$
If I recall it correctly.

Comment: It supposed to be $f \circ g=f(g(x))$, but your hint is pretty good and helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You are right, fixed it.